# can I get rid of the open/new/save toolbar in gedit 3.18.3?

Tags: gedit

In gedit 3.18.3, there is a bar at the top with the options "Open", "Create new document" (as a hat-type symbol with a plus inside), and then to the far right after a long stretch of blank/unused space, a button for "Save".  This toolbar or whatever it is is located below the file menu and above the tabs/names of any files that are open.

Can I get rid of it?  The functionality is redundant, and other than saving I do not use the open or new document functions from within gedit very often.  This toolbar is annoyingly conspicuous to me, and takes up way too much space considering its extremely limited usefulness (to me, at least).

Alternatively, if I cannot get rid of it, can I customize it so I can at least utilize the space for functions that I do use more often?  Can I resize it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure would it helps, but you can press `F11` to maximize useful space of gedit window.

Comment: Switch to leafpad, it's  a barebones editor like gedit used to be.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is a bug which isn't fixed yet.

You could use templates to start your files :

```
mkdir ~/Templates
touch ~/Templates/Text/File.txt
```